# Get title/color of series from Flex Chart

Tags: apache-flex, charts

I've created a chart in flex and now I need to get the series' label and colors, but I cannot find a way to do that. Do you know a way to retrieve them?

I know I can use the Legend Control, but I don't need that. I just need to get an arraycollection with series' label and colors

Answer (score 0):

found the answer .. 
this is what i used to get the value from the first series (lineseries)
myChart.legendData[0].element.getStyle('lineStroke');